# how to remove ' ' in bind variable in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make search query by option value in jsp! And there is 3 options

this is my query and when i execute, And it didn't work. 
 i think it's beause of bind variable's converted with ' '
how can i remove ' ' in sql?
I'm using oracle DB

this is original sql.

```
<![CDATA[
    select bId, bName, bTitle, bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent 
    from mvc_board where :keyField like :keyWord
    ]]>
```

it's changed like this

```
 select bId, bName, bTitle, bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent 
    from mvc_board where 'keyField' like 'keyWord'
```

this sql work but i wish bTitle can be changed by variable

```
<![CDATA[
        select bId, bName, bTitle, bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent 
            from mvc_board where bTitle like :keyWord
                ]]>
```

Comment: what's CDATA, where does it come from..? I think you need to tag with your application also.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not very helpful. Did you get an error - if so which which one? Or did you get the wrong result - in which case what did you get and what did you expect? You can't bind a column name (`:keyField`), you can only bind variables, but it isn't really clear if that is the (only) problem. And without more context about CDATA and how you're processing it, we can't really suggest alternatives. You need to generate the statement with the column name substituted in, instead of binding it; but how you do that really depends on what you are doing now...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan oh I can remove  CDATA!

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks i didn't know that  I can only bind variables! then to change column should i make if() ?

Comment: I mean your problem is not directly related to sql, we also need to know your `app.` or `programming lang.` to be able to help you.

Comment: @g.dev - like I said, it depends on what you are doing now - where the base query and the column name are coming from, how you're currently running and binding the statement, etc. We need more context. I'm not sure where the empty string fits in though - is that the column name (!?) or the variable, and what do you want ot happen if it is empty (null)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE()` function.

```
SELECT REPLACE('your_value', chr(32), '') FROM yourtable
```

`chr(32)` is the whitespace.